# How can I build a Pandas matrix from a 3 dimensional table?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have built a Pandas dataset with 3 dimensions that looks like this:

```
colors         b                 g                 r
categories Alpha  Beta Omega Alpha  Beta Omega Alpha Beta Omega
score       40.0  25.0   NaN  26.0  76.0  41.0  49.0  NaN  26.0
```

My goal is to build a matrix* table from it, using scores as cell values, and having axis that represent colors and categories such as the following:

```
colors/categories Alpha Beta Omega
r                   75    0    0
b                   0     65   0
g                   41    0    2
```

How can I build something like this with Pandas?

(*) I am not 100% sure whether what I am trying to achieve is actually called a matrix table so please feel free to correct my question. Colors can be more than r/g/b so the table is not necessarily a square either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape, then remove first level with `score` if necessary by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and last replace `NaN`s to `0` and cast to `int`:

```
df = df.stack(0).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
categories  Alpha  Beta  Omega
colors                        
b              40    25      0
g              26    76     41
r              49     0     26
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great. Out of curiosity, is this a matrix table? I want to make sure my question is clear and accurate for future readers.